# Bluetooth Headset problems in Windows 8.1

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, bluetooth, headphones, windows

I have a Mid 2012 MBP MD101 and a Sony DR-BTN200 Bluetooth Headset that works wonders on Mavericks and my Xperia S.

In Windows 8.1 though, it is only working for a couple minutes each time i connect the MBP to the Headset after a reboot, then they go completely silent; I have to reboot to get them to work again.

I can't go OS X only as the Xamarin project is still lagged behind VS.

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you have access to another (preferably non-Apple HW based) Windows 8.1 system to verify whether the connection between computer and headset is more stable there?

Comment: An old Lenovo laptop of mine used to work just fine